# Select posts for Category with Child categories and pagination

Tags: laravel, post, eloquent, categories

I just started with Laravel and Eloquent and can't image for myself how to select posts for specific category (and subcategories for the parent category) with pagination...
Here is my SQL query:

```
select posts.id, posts.published_at
from posts
inner join category_post as  cp on cp.post_id = posts.id
inner join categories as c on cp.category_id = c.id
where c.id in (1,11,12,13)
order by posts.published_at desc, posts.id desc
offset 0
limit 15;
```

Comment: you may use Post::
with(['categories' => function ($q) {
   $q->paginate();
}]);

Comment: Does it select me posts for are specific categories (parent category and children categories) and paginate it?
In your example I didn't see any data about categories ID.

Comment: It will be already handled as you are using with.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.id', 'posts.published_at')
    ->join('category_post as cp', 'cp.post_id', 'posts.id')
    ->join('categories as c', 'cp.category_id', 'c.id')
    ->whereIn('c.id', [1, 11, 12, 13])
    ->orderBy('posts.published_at', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Then, in your view, using `$posts->links()` will echo out  the pagination links. This is a minimal example. Of course, you can use another layout like a `<table>` but the links should be outside the loop.

```xml
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <p>{{ $post->id }}</p>
            <p>{{ $post->published_at }}</p>
            <hr>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

Documentation:

- [SELECT](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#select-statements)
- [JOINS](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins)
- [WHERE IN](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#additional-where-clauses)
- [ORDER BY](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#ordering)
- [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/pagination)